# how to check if a user email already exist

Tags: php, laravel

In laravel, when a new user is registering to my site and the email they use already exist in the database. how can tell the user that the email already exist ?. I am new to laravel framework. A sample code would be nice too.

Comment: Before going to write the query... it is always good to search the ready made solution is there. Good Question +1

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The validation feature built into Laravel lets you check lots of things, including if a value already exists in the database. Here's an overly simplified version of what you need. In reality you'd probably want to redirect back to the view with the form and show some error messages.

```
// Get the value from the form
$input['email'] = Input::get('email');

// Must not already exist in the `email` column of `users` table
$rules = array('email' => 'unique:users,email');

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    echo 'That email address is already registered. You sure you don\'t have an account?';
}
else {
    // Register the new user or whatever.
}
```

);

Laravel has built-in human readable error messages for all its validation. You can get an array of the these messages via: `$validator->messages();`

You can learn more about validation and what all you can do with it in the [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/validation).

Comment: Just FYI for future reference. If you have a space after "users," `'required|unique:users, email'` it will cause the SQL statement to fail.

Answer (score 13):

**Basic Usage Of Unique Rule**

```
'email' => 'unique:users'
```

**Specifying A Custom Column Name**

```
'email' => 'unique:users,email_address'
```

**Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID**

```
'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,10'
```

**Adding Additional Where Clauses**

You may also specify more conditions that will be added as "where" clauses to the query:

```
'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,NULL,id,account_id,1'
```

The above is from [the documentation of Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation)

You could add:

```
public static $rules = [
    'email' => 'unique:users,email'
];
```

You can add more rules to the $rules like:

```
public static $rules = [
        'email' => 'required|unique:users,email'
];
```

It will automatically produce the error messages

and add:

```
public static function isValid($data)
{
    $validation = Validator::make($data, static::$rules);

    if ($validation->passes())
    {
        return true;
    }
    static::$errors = $validation->messages();
    return false;
}
```

to the model *User.php*

Then in the function you're using to register, you could add:

```
if ( ! User::isValid(Input::all()))
{
    return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors(User::$errors);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
if(sizeof(Users::where('email','=',Input::get('email'))->get()) > 0) return 'Error : User email exists';
```

Answer (score 3):

The great resource is only Laravel Documentation @ 
[enter link description here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#basic-usage)

I also did like below when integrating user management system

```
 $user = Input::get('username');
  $email = Input::get('email');

$validator = Validator::make(
        array(
            'username' => $user,
            'email' => $email
        ),
        array(
            'username' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users'
        )
  );
  if ($validator->fails())
    {
        // The given data did not pass validation
        echo 'invalid credentials;';
        // we can also  return same page and then displaying in Bootstap Warning Well
    }
    else {
        // Register the new user or whatever.
        $user = new User;
        $user->email = Input::get('email');
       $user->username = Input::get('username');

        $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
        $user->save();

        $theEmail = Input::get('email');
         // passing data to thanks view 
        return View::make('thanks')->With('displayEmail', $theEmail);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 public function userSignup(Request $request, User $data){
    # check user if match with database user
    $users = User::where('email', $request->email)->get();

    # check if email is more than 1
    if(sizeof($users) > 0){
        # tell user not to duplicate same email
        $msg = 'This user already signed up !';
        Session::flash('userExistError', $msg);
        return back();
    }

    // create new files
    $data = new User;
    $data->name = $request->name;
    $data->email = $request->email;
    $data->password = md5($request->password);
    $data->save();

    //return back
    Session::flash('status', 'Thanks, you have successfully signup'); 
    Session::flash('name', $request->name);

    # after every logic redirect back
    return back();
}
```

> I think when u try something like this you earn a smooth check using Model

Comment: The User class arg is a Model.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the **Validator.**

**In your Controller.**

```
$validator =  $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
```

**In View**

```
  @error('email') <span class="text-danger error">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $this->validate($request, [
        'fname' => 'required',
        'lname' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|min:4|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);
```

Try This